# boost::fibonacci_heap copy constructor corrupts the source heap

Tags: c++, boost

I have a member function that prints a snapshot of a boost::fibonacci_heap

```
virtual void printSnapshot(std::ostream& ss) {
  Heap heap(this->heap);
  double prev_price = DBL_MAX;
  while(heap.size() > 0) {
    const Order& order = heap.top();
    if(order.price != prev_price) {
      if(prev_price != DBL_MAX) ss << std::endl;
      ss << order.price << " | ";
    }
    ss << order.quantity << " ";
    prev_price = order.price;
    heap.pop();
  }
  ss << std::endl;
}
```

I call this member function in another member function, which does

```
while(std::getline(stream, line)) {
    ... // do something on this->heap.
    this->printSnapshot(std::cout);
}
```

Since the heap is created through a copy constructor at the beginning of "printSnapshot", then "printSnapshot" should change this->heap. However, this program leads to segment fault, while the following does not:

```
while(std::getline(stream, line)) {
    ... // do something on this->heap.
    // this->printSnapshot(std::cout);
}
```

Now, if we add a const keyword to the definition of printSnapshot, i.e.

```
virtual void printSnapshot(std::ostream& ss) const {
  Heap heap(this->heap);
  double prev_price = DBL_MAX;
  while(heap.size() > 0) {
    const Order& order = heap.top();
    if(order.price != prev_price) {
      if(prev_price != DBL_MAX) ss << std::endl;
      ss << order.price << " | ";
    }
    ss << order.quantity << " ";
    prev_price = order.price;
    heap.pop();
  }
  ss << std::endl;
}
```

The segment fault disappears. How could this be explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of `fibonacci_heap` that takes a `lvalue reference` (non-const) apparently doesn't do the right things.

It's not documented what it should do: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html#idp21129704-bb

I assume this might be a reportable bug. I'll look into this a bit.

> **UPDATE** Surprisingly the behaviour of this constructor is apparently equivalent to move-construction:
>
> ```
> #ifndef BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES
>     /// \copydoc boost::heap::priority_queue::priority_queue(priority_queue &&)
>     fibonacci_heap(fibonacci_heap && rhs):
>         super_t(std::move(rhs)), top_element(rhs.top_element)
>     {
>         roots.splice(roots.begin(), rhs.roots);
>         rhs.top_element = NULL;
>     }
>
>     fibonacci_heap(fibonacci_heap & rhs):
>         super_t(rhs), top_element(rhs.top_element)
>     {
>         roots.splice(roots.begin(), rhs.roots);
>         rhs.top_element = NULL;
>     }
> ```
>
> The latter has the weird side-effect of simply removing all roots from the original (intrusive) list. This looks like a clear-cut bug.
>
> Simply removing this constructor makes the code work.

The essential workaround is to avoid the lvalue-ref constructor:

```
Heap cloned(static_cast<Heap const&>(this->heap));
```

Meanwhile here's a self-contained reproducer:

```
#include <boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

namespace {
#undef DBL_MAX
    static double DBL_MAX = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

    std::mt19937 rng;
    //std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(100, 4000);
    std::discrete_distribution<int> dist({1,1,1,1,1,1});
    static auto price_gen = [&] { 
        static double values[] = {52.40, 12.30, 87.10, 388., 0.10, 23.40};
        return values[dist(rng)]; 
    };
}


struct Order {
    double price      = price_gen();
    unsigned quantity = rand() % 4 + 1;

    double subtotal() const { return price * quantity; }

    bool operator<(Order const& other) const { return subtotal() < other.subtotal(); }
};

using Heap = boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<Order>;

struct Y {
    virtual void printSnapshot(std::ostream &ss) {
        //Heap cloned(static_cast<Heap const&>(this->heap));
        Heap cloned(this->heap);
        double prev_price = DBL_MAX;

        while (cloned.size() > 0) {
            const Order &order = cloned.top();

            if (order.price != prev_price) {
                if (prev_price != DBL_MAX)
                    ss << std::endl;
                ss << order.price << " | ";
            }
            ss << order.quantity << " ";
            prev_price = order.price;
            cloned.pop();
        }
        ss << std::endl;
    }

    void generateOrders() {
        for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
            heap.push({});
        }
    }

    Heap heap;
};

int main() {
    Y y;
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        y.generateOrders();
        y.printSnapshot(std::cout);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've reported the library issue as **[ticket #1100: _Rogue fibonacci_heap constructor corrupts source_](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11000)**

Comment: And it has been [fixed in the development branch](https://github.com/boostorg/heap/commit/6ca2c4c39df3e6fe9914e7b1df34770b7dcddb7d)